# .Net 5 Scaffoling "Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors." But No error

Tags: c#, .net, webapi, scaffold

I've got wierd situation,
When Im trying to update db Model by using

**"dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold  Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --force"**

I'm gettin an error
"Build failed. Use dotnet build to see the errors."

BUT when i rebuild solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWvN9.png)

Rebuild succeeded.

Any idea what is happing? I hadn't problems with that before

Comment: Is the project you're running this on referencing the Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools nuget package?

Comment: Yes, but what is weird. I'm using Rider, but when I switched to visual studio, and used pmConsole everything worked fine again, but via terminal not.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure any assembly projects included in your main project build successfully.

Clean your project and make sure it is also built successfully. You might get the error **Build started… Build failed.** if one of the projects has a problem building successfully.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).